# excel vba error 1004 Range

Tags: vba, excel

So i've got 2 Range() items:

```
Set myRange1 = Range("E2:E8,D9:D12,F9:F12,J2:J8,I9:I12,K9:K12,O2:O8,N9:N12,P9:P12,E14:E20,D21:D24,F21:F24,J14:J20,I21:I24,K21:K24,O14:O20,N21:N24,P21:P24,E26:E32,D33:D36,F33:F36,J26:J32,I33:I36,K33:K36,O26:O32,N33:N36,P33:P36")
Set myRange2 = Range("C6:C9,E7:E9,G7:G9,J6:J9,L7:L9,N7:N9,Q6:Q9,S7:S9,U7:U9,X6:X9,Z7:Z9,AB7:AB9,C12:C15,E13:E15,G13:G15,J12:J15,L13:L15,N13:N15,Q12:Q15,S13:S15,U13:U15,X12:X15,Z13:Z15,AB13:AB15,C18:C21,E19:E21,G19:G21,J18:J21,L19:L21,N19:N21,Q18:Q21,S19:S21,U19:U21,X18:X21,Z19:Z21,AB19:AB21")
```

myRange1 is fine, myRange2 throws Run-time Error 1004 Method 'Range' of Object '_Global' Failed.

Does anyone know why? Is there too many ranges in a range? In my opinion they're both pretty long.

Comment: Not too many addresses, but too many characters.  i.e. it is the length of the string being passed to the Range method that is the issue - it has a maximum length of 255 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Too many** is the correct answer. However, if you want to use them try this trick:

```
Set myRange2 = Range("C6:C9,E7:E9,G7:G9,J6:J9,L7:L9,N7:N9,Q6:Q9,S7:S9,U7:U9,X6:X9,Z7:Z9,AB7:AB9")
Set myRange2 = Union(myRange2,range("C12:C15,E13:E15,G13:G15,J12:J15,L13:L15,N13:N15,Q12:Q15,S13:S15,U13:U15,X12:X15,Z13:Z15,AB13:AB15,C18:C21,E19:E21,G19:G21,J18:J21,L19:L21,N19:N21,Q18:Q21,S19:S21,U19:U21,X18:X21,Z19:Z21,AB19:AB21"))
```

You can have up to 30 arguments in a Union:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx

But if you increment like in the code above, you can go like this forever.