# VBA Delete row if

Tags: vba, excel, delete-row

All i want to do is to optimize my current delete row code.
At this stage this step take to much time.

```
        Dim miesiac2 As Integer '--->current month
        miesiac2 = Range("b1").Value
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = [A65536].End(xlUp).Row
        For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1) = miesiac2 Then Rows(i & ":" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        Next i
```

So... If column A  equals current month then EntireRow.Delete
Any idea?

Comment: im guessing "Mount" is month?

Comment: (a) You never assign a value to `miesiac2`.  (b) It won't be noticeable, but you will get a **small** improvement by changing `Rows(i & ":" & i)` to `Rows(i)`.  (c) Have you set `Application.Calculation` to `xlCalculationManual`?  And `Application.ScreenUpdating` to `False`?

Comment: (a) don' worry about that, just add it to my 'question
(b) i'll check it. Thx
(c) yeap

Comment: The best way is to save the rows with `miesiac2` as a specific range and then delete the range only once.

Comment: Have you checked your locals to see that miesiac2 is being populated by the correct data

Comment: Lowpar: all code work fine, just need to upgrade delete method

Comment: Vityata:I also think that this would be the best way

Comment: @MaciekChilu - then start making the unions like in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44432003/excel-vba-error-1004-range/44432078#44432078 + if you write the `Application.ScreenUpdating  = False` it would work really fast.

Comment: Use `Find` rather than looking at each row in turn. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's something I have built so far:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim miesiac2        As Long
    Dim LastRow         As Long
    Dim i               As Long
    Dim rRange          As Range

    miesiac2 = Range("b1").Value
    LastRow = [A65536].End(xlUp).Row 'xl2003

    For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1) = miesiac2 Then
            If rRange Is Nothing Then
                Set rRange = Rows(i)
            Else
                Set rRange = Union(rRange, Rows(i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    If Not rRange Is Nothing Then rRange.Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It uses a `Union` and it selects the rows instead of deleting them. Its for visibility reasons, but you can fix it.
Furthermore, the 65K rows are only in Excel 2003, in later versions the rows are 1Mln+. Last but not least - do not use `integer` in Excel, its slow and dangerous.

Comment: Super, thx. One change: 

 If Not (rRange Is Nothing) Then rRange.Select

Comment: One more error here... When current mounth do not exist then this code is selecting all date... not good

Comment: @MaciekChilu - strange. I have just checked it on an empty sheet with 3-4 values in the first column and it was working quite ok - not selecting anything.

Comment: dont need to worry about. Just add IF statement and its fine ^^

Answer (score 0):

This is what I could cook up in hurry

```
Sub delete_on_condition()
    Dim wb_export As Workbook
    Dim wb_export_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim arr_raw_dump As Variant
    Dim arr_final
    Dim findcell As Range

    Set wb_export = ThisWorkbook ' CHANGE IT IF REQURIED
    Set wb_export_sheet = wb_export.Sheets(1)    'CHANGE IT IF REQUIRED

    Dim ctr As Long
    ctr = 0
    With wb_export_sheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' OR With wb_export_sheet.USEDRANGE

    Do
         Set findcell = .Find("SOME TEXT")
            If ctr = 0 And findcell Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "No data found"
                Exit Sub
            End If

         wb_export_sheet.Rows(findcell.Row).Delete
         Set findcell = .Find("SOMETEXT")
         ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop While Not findcell Is Nothing
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thx, but problem alredy has been solved . Vityata solution is working really fast. It speed up my App. from 12 to 2 minuts